# How to Combine 2 Foreach Loops with Different Array Results?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, shuffle

```
$dogruA = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
$yanlisA = array("3", "4", "7", "8", "10");

shuffle($dogruA);
shuffle($yanlisA);

    foreach ($dogruA as $dogru) :
        if ($dogru != '') {
            ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answerSik[]"
                       value="<?php echo $dogru; ?>"><?php echo $dogru; ?>
            <?php
        }
    endforeach;

    foreach ($yanlisA as $yanlis) :
        if ($yanlis!= '') { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answerSik[]"
                       value="0"><?php echo $yanlis; ?>
            <?php
        }
    endforeach;
```

How do I combine these two foreach?

I tried these:

```
foreach( $dogruA as $dogru and $yanlisA as $yanlis)
```

and

```
foreach (array_combine($dogruA, $yanlisA) as $dogru => $yanlis) {
```

But I did not succeed. 
How do I use a method?

Comment: Use array_merge instead of array_combine

Comment: you should use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and then [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) if you want unique values from merged array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first merge your array,like

```
$new_array = array_merge($dogruA, $yanlisA);
```

then after pass it to foreach  with array_unique() method it takes care of array repeated values,

```
foreach(array_unique($new_array) as $single){
 echo $single;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
foreach (array_merge($dogruA, $yanlisA) as $dogru => $yanlis) {
```

Array_combine has a different function than what you need here

And as correctly posted in the comment above if you need only unique values you should use this

```
foreach (array_unique(array_merge($dogruA, $yanlisA)) as $dogru => $yanlis) {
```

Comment: array_combine() is the method which takes one array as key array and another one is to values array

Comment: Its ok brother but some small mistake can misguide some of the others.